# Why Accuracy of decision tree and knn are exact same (also after feature scaling)?

Tags: algorithm, data-science

I have applies decision tree and KNN model on Pima Indian diabetes dataset. I got the exact same accuracy with or without feature selection whereas non-trie ml algorithm prediction varies with feature selection.

[image: after feature selection[![][1]][image: ][1]]

Comment: Most likely you messed up somewhere, this is very unlikely to happen. Debug your code!

Comment: you haven't redefined `clf`, e.g. in In [9] you use same clf from In [8]

Comment: @giliev thanks, got it. How can calculate accuracy in KNN Regressor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using clf to predict in all cases.

`x_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)` is where the error is. Change the classifier to the appropriate one for prediction (in your case that'd be `KNN`)

PS: In your case the issue is trivial - However, please post actual code instead of images so that others can easily try and replicate the error.

Comment: Thanks got it. How can calculate accuracy in KNN Regressor?